# Auto complete in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, skype-bots

Is there any way to do autocomplete (from a database or JSON) in the Bot framework emulator?

Currently I am using the Bot Framework emulator and I want to know if there is any possible way of using @symbol to populate (autocomplete) data. Finally I want to know if I can do this in Skype.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you qould plan on implementing this in skype without access to the client code.  Have you looked into that at all?

Comment: Can you explain more what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi @KunalMukherjee , am trying to populate data's in bot emulator framework like auto complete. please refer the link which i want expecting " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/kes/overview ", like that image from this link. am trying past three days , if you know please help me.

Comment: Its not possible using bot framework's default `iframe` in `webchat`. You need a custom **chat window** something like this [Example Custom Chat Window](https://www.hdfcbank.com/) to implement what you are thinking. However you can use `$.autocomplete` in jQuery to populate the values in a custom chat window. To construct a custom chat window, you need `DirectLine` to send and recieve messages to your bot to and fro.

Comment: thanks for replay @KunalMukherjee , your idea is great but my scenario i want to depended on emulator or finally i want to use in skype. so please suggest me , is there any way ?