# Query Auto-Completion in c# bot in bot framework

Tags: c#, jquery, autocomplete, botframework

I want to implement autocomplete in my c# bot which i developed using microsoft bot framework and added into my portal as iframe.
is it possible to implement query suggestion or query auto-completion in this bot?
i tried this solution also

[Auto complete in Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47926061/auto-complete-in-bot-framework)

but i did not find it helpful for me.
can i use jquery auto-completion here ?

https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can i use jquery auto-completion here ?

Based on my test, we can attach [jQuery Autocomplete widgets](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) to webchat input box. The following sample code is for your reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>
    <style>
        .wc-chatview-panel {
            width: 350px;
            height: 500px;
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mybot" />
</body>
</html>
<script>
    BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: "{your_directline_secret}" },
        user: { id: 'You' },
        bot: { id: '{your_bot_id}' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("mybot"));

    $(function () {

        var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure", "COBOL"];

        $("input.wc-shellinput").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
        });

    })
</script>
```

**Test result:**

[image]

**Note**: I enter `a`, it show a list items for my selecting, and then I select an item, such as **ActionScript**, if I directly click send button, it will only send `a` to bot. To avoid it, we can manually enter a white-space (or other characters) and remove them before click send button.

Comment: i tried this one.. when i type a it shows me some related output if i select any of them like Asp and try to send message it send only a instead of Asp

Comment: how can i overcome this problem..it will not be user friendly is i have to add any white space or character eveytime

Comment: @chandra, were you able to solve that issue? we have to add white space everytime.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this issue since 4 days.Finally I made it work.

You need to write jQuery for input.wc-shellinput element. I have implemented it with azure search.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="../Styles/Skins/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Styles/skins/customwebchat.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="styles/pages.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>`enter code here`
    <div id="body-container">

        <div class="bot-container">
            <div id="bot" class="snow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--  <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/botchat.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/botchat.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/CognitiveServices.js"></script>
    <script>

        const speechOptions = {

            speechRecognizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechRecognizer({ subscriptionKey: '' }),

            speechSynthesizer: new CognitiveServices.SpeechSynthesizer({

                gender: CognitiveServices.SynthesisGender.Female,

                subscriptionKey: '',

                voiceName: 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (en-US, JessaRUS)'

            })

        };

        BotChat.App({
            directLine: { secret: '' },
            user: { id: 'userid' },
            bot: { id: 'botid' },
            speechOptions: speechOptions,
            resize: 'detect'
        }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.autocompleteInline.js"></script>


    <link href="/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/tutorial.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/Content/jquery.autocompleteInline.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script  type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            $("input.wc-shellinput").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: suggestUri,
                        dataType: "json",
                        headers: {
                            "api-key": searchServiceApiKey,
                            "Content-Type": "application/json",

                            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                            "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE"
                        },
                        data: JSON.stringify({
                            top: 5,
                            fuzzy: false,
                            suggesterName: "", //Suggester Name according to azure search index.
                            search: request.term
                        }),
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.value && data.value.length > 0) {
                                userinput = data.value;
                                console.log(userinput);
                                response(data.value.map(x => x["@search.text"]));
                            }
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 3,
                position: {
                    my: "left top",
                    at: "left bottom",
                    collision: "fit flip"
                },
                select: function (Event, ui) {

                    $(document).ready(function () {

                        var input = document.getElementsByClassName("wc-shellinput")[0];
                        var lastValue = input.value;
                        input.value = ui.item.value;
                        var event = new CustomEvent('input', { bubbles: true });
                        // hack React15
                        event.simulated = true;
                        // hack React16
                        var tracker = input._valueTracker;
                        if (tracker) {
                            tracker.setValue(lastValue);
                        }

                        input.dispatchEvent(event);
                    })

                    $('wc-textbox').val("");
                    Event.preventDefault();

                    $(".wc-send:first").click();
                }

            });
        });


    </script>
    <script>
        var searchServiceName = "";
        var searchServiceApiKey = "";
        var indexName = "";
        var apiVersion = "";

        var suggestUri = "https://" + searchServiceName + ".search.windows.net/indexes/" + indexName + "/docs/suggest?api-version=" + apiVersion;
        var autocompleteUri = "https://" + searchServiceName + ".search.windows.net/indexes/" + indexName + "/docs/autocomplete?api-version=" + apiVersion;
        var searchUri = "https://" + searchServiceName + ".search.windows.net/indexes/" + indexName + "/docs/search?api-version=" + apiVersion;
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My Sample API Output:
{
    "@odata.context": "URL",
    "value": [{
            "suggestedItems": [
                "where are you",
                "where have you been",
            ]
        },
        {
            "suggestedItems": [
                "How are you?"
            ]
        }
    ]
} 
caught error at 

response(data.value.map(x => x["@search.text"]));

Error Message:Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'label' of undefined
I tried replace @search.text with "value" and "@data.context" but still am getting error.
I want to display all questions data

Comment: I found solution for my fix  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101639/jquery-autocomplete-error-cannot-read-property-label-of-undefined/55114046#55114046(here)